# Cant find the prime number

Tags: c

I know i could use an extra variable counting the dvisors but my problem is why will this line not do? 
prime = num / 1 == num && num / num == 1;
Also check below for comments in the problematic code. thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long num = 0;
    long req = 0;
    int control = 0;
    int div = 1;             
    int prime;

    printf("Give starting number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num );
    printf("\nGive required numbers: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &req);;
    while(req > control)
    {       
        printf("\nNumber is: %d ", num);
        prime = num / 1 == num && num / num == 1; /*This lines here why dosnt thi work?*/

        if(prime)   /*Also here lets say the above line work with what do i avaluate the if with so it only prints tha asterisk for the prime numbers?*/
            printf("* ");
        printf("Equal Divisors are: ");

            while(div <= num)
            {
                if(num % div ==0)
                    printf("%d ", div);
                div++;
            }

        if(req == control)
            break;

        num++;
        control++;
        div=1;                      


        printf("\n");       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not how you check for a prime. Any number divides by itself and one, primes are the ones that don't divide by anything *else*

Comment: Oops thanks so would this work? prime = num / 1 == num && num / num == 1 && well what could i put here?

Comment: case num is 4 : 4/1 == 4 && 4 / 4 == 1 is true, but 4 isn't prime.( divisible by the number of another.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Leeor pointed this out in his/her comment: that's not how you check for primes.  Every number will meet your criteria.

Primes are numbers that ONLY divide evenly by themselves and by 1.  So you'd have to loop through all other divisors, up to num/2, and make sure they don't give an integer result.  (Technically you only have to loop through all PRIME number divisors -- 2,3,5,7,11,etc. -- but that's harder to do.)

EDIT: As @thb pointed out in a comment, you'd have to loop through all other divisors up to sqrt(num), not num/2.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
Set a Boolean variable to "True" (meaning "yes, it's a prime").
Loop from 2 to sqrt(num).
    If num divided by the loop counter is an integer, then...
        It's NOT a prime number.
        Set the Boolean variable to "False".
        If you can exit the loop there, great. But no big deal if you can't.
After the loop, if the Boolean variable = "True" then it's a prime number.  If it's "False" then it's not a prime number.
```

Comment: Indeed, you'd only have to loop up to sqrt(num), no?

Comment: @thb WOW! You're right! How come I never thought of that?? Thanks. :)

Comment: So how would i go about writing the prime =?

Comment: @JohnJSD I added pseudocode to my answer. Please mark it as "The Answer" if it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is with the ordering of expressions.  The line

```
prime = num / 1 == num && num / num == 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    const bool a = ((num / 1) == num);
    const bool b = ((num / num) == 1);
    prime = a && b;
}
```

This is an easy error to make.  Anyway, one doubts that `prime = a && b;` is what you meant.